# Why did only a few companies make microcomputers to begin with?

Tags: computer-architecture, history

I was watching a program about Clive Sinclair and they used to advertise a computer and then design and build it within 3-6 months.

So 8-bit computers must have been fairly simple to design and build.

But were they? Or were the engineers pretty much geniuses?

Were people like Wosniac and Clive Sinclairs engineers amazingly talented or were 8-bit computers just really easy to make?

From watching documentaries, the actual computer seems not to difficult to make. You just need a processor, some ram, and a video output (all these things pre-made) and just need to design a printed circuit board to join them all together. I imagine many people with a degree in electronics could have done it??

The challenging bit seems like the operating system (usually a version of BASIC). And writing the documentation.

I read once that Bill Gates programmed a version of BASIC in under a week.

So, in terms of hardness, could most electronics students create an 8-bit computer or is it actually quite hard to do?

Comment: You write, "Were people like Wosniac and Clive Sinclairs engineers amazingly talented or were 8-bit computers just really easy to make?" That's not the dilemma. They were, instead, incredibly lucky and very motivated. And no, 8-bit computers weren't "just really easy to make." I lived through that period, building one computer out of 7400 parts before buying an Altair 8800 (and later, two 4k dynamic RAM cards that were fundamentally designed wrong and forced me to suffer for over six weeks trying to find the problems I was ill-equipped to deal with at the time.) None of this was easy then.

Comment: @jonk But the zx80 didn't have 7400 parts. It had about 20 chips and as far as i can tell from the pictures. As well as other parts. Why did your one have 7400 parts? Well I guess if you count the wires in a prototype board before making a printed circuit.

Comment: @jsotola My question is, in that time period was the expertise needed to build an 8-bit computer farily common. That's why I tagged it "history".

Comment: This question might get better responses at [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/). Or they might ask you to be more specific about what you're asking.

Comment: @zooby There are partial ALU parts in the 7400 line and plenty of support chips. Yes, I wire-wrapped like a demon back then. Still have my tools from that time. And I was able to find good books on computer design, back then. So there must have been plenty of good folks, even then. Since, the world population has tripled. So I'd guess there are more today than then. But it was, then, and eclectic group -- those of us still teenagers and making computers, doing rocketry, making telescopes, turning typewriters into printers, assembling our own terminals (ADM3A in my case), designing modems, etc.

Comment: @jonk sounds like fun. So sounds like there were quite a number of people who were making these but only a small minority had the luck or knowhow to turn their hobby into a business. Would that be fair to say?

Comment: @zooby I think you need to understand (and you do?) something that, sadly, too many who "make it" fail to realize. They often imagine that it is their smarts or their hard work that made them who they are. But it was, in almost every case, their luck. I make more than most people I know. But I also know that it was on the backs of those who went before I did, those who made and paid for the libraries and schools, those who created so much I depended upon. I was mostly lucky. And yet, as a child, I had to work the fields as a common laborer just to survive, too. But mostly, I was lucky.

Comment: @zooby So, while hard work and smarts and motivation are all very important in helping to take advantage of opportunity and luck when it happens, none of that makes any of us special. There are many more people who are smarter, work harder, and are more motivated. And they weren't so lucky. So I'm glad to see you write "luck." It's the most important factor in one's life.

Comment: you need access to a foundary

Comment: @jonk well I'm sure a lot of successful people are also born with better than average brain functions. I know Bill Gates for example was lucky but also scored best in a math test in his state, so was also extremely smart. But I digress as he didn't make any computers.

Comment: @zooby I scored a perfect 800 on the math section of my SAT after HS. But I didn't have a well-vetted and wealthy attorney dad with connections to IBM, just at the right moment and place, and a willingness to buy someone else's DOS software for a small sum and then run with it, not looking back. My dad died when I was 7 and there was no welfare then. I had to work as a laborer at the age of 12 just to survive. I lived in a house without walls, cold. I had no access to health care. As I say, luck is the dominating factor. Not the best math score.

Comment: @zooby I do count myself one of the most lucky in the world. What helped deepen that lesson was when my wife and I put our home and family at risk helping families escape raging war; hiding them, listening to their cries, comforting them and their remaining children during long nights. Despite the decades now, I still cry for what I was only able to partially understand and share, yet still remember today too well.

Comment: @zooby Yes, I worked fields to survive. But I was very, very lucky. I had access to libraries where I could study, good schools, good roads and easily begged materials to supply my hobbies. Many work harder. Many suffer more. Few are lucky. Fewer still, lucky enough to make news. (I made local news when I built that computer.) I never forget luck is 1st. The rest? It's 2nd and 3rd order effects. Hard work and genius makes great print for a newspaper. But the story that doesn't make it is how lucky those who make the news are. We owe everything we are to others. More than we can ever pay back.

Comment: Be careful of your interpretation of history.  Woz has been portrayed as a mad genius by in particular a certain individual and that individuals influence on people has head to a specific writing of history.  Same goes for Gates and Allen.  Whatever technical skills they had were not what made them household names, a lot of luck, and a lot of non technical skills, sales, marketing, confidence, attitude, pressure, and being at the right place at the right time, which in part was due to vision.

Comment: In order for either of those four people to become household names there were a long list of non-household names that used technical skills (and non) to build the foundation, history, reference designs or ideas, that they stood on the shoulders of.

Comment: No these were no easier then than they are now.  If it were possible to do an apples to apples comparison todays college students would have a very hard time making it through a design like that. Have a hard time with today's (relatively simple) tech if you dont hand them most of the answers and only make them figure out a few simple problems.

Comment: The last layer of folks that made Woz possible, MOS and Commodore (Apple was an also-ran compared to the leading computer companies of the day one of which was Commodore) didnt just have to know one, zero, and, or, not.  The masks were hand drawn, had to be able to create a gate by drawing the layers.  plus put all the gates together to make a working chip.  have the smarts to know where the microcoded line was to have a chance at success in a survivable number of chip spins.  Similar to having to know how to make paint to be a painter, vs what came later.

Comment: THEN folks like Woz and Roberts could come along and buy parts and design systems around them, they were certainly not the first to use those respective parts, nor were they designing in the blind.  Nor were they the only ones.  There were both technical and non-technical reasons why they got where they got relative to the ones we dont talk about as much.  Would there even be a 6502 or much less an Apple without Commodore's involvement in history?  Probably not, or there would be other names instead.

Comment: Because the market had to be proved...

Comment: @zooby You say "to begin with" and "Z80" as if they have some close relationship. Try 4004 8008 then maybe F8 (doom doom) SC/MP 6800 8080 6502  ... . By the time you get to Z80 it's MUCH closer to plug and play - but as Jonk says, easy to go wrong. I wirewrapped a 6802 system and vero-boarded a SC/MP! :-( :-).  The Z80 has dynamic RAM refresh built in. Way back when eproms had 3 supply rails (1702) and even the 2708 needed HV programming. Static RAMs (2102? ...) made life easier and harder. Sir Clive was genius enough - but the basic concepts were "easy enough in retrospect". ...

Comment: ... Sir Clive's teams early genius showed in getting the ZX80 to use the Z80 to do display control as well as processing (with a screen that blanked out when you pressed a key.) || Wozniak's Apple 1 / II genius was seen in things like the IWM (Integrated Woz Machine) that implemented a floppy disk controller using a hex or so of D flip flops in the days when the 1771 was almost a glimmer in someone's eye. Utter brilliance. || Memories .... :-)

Answer (score 3):

The 8-bit computers that were practical as products were made around 8-bit microprocessors. "Real" computer professionals used them in embedded systems but looked down on a computer made from them as toys which left it to the younger more brave people who were not yet in the profession. To get inexpensive subsystems for display and storage did take a lot of ingenuity (Wozniak). A wire wrapped TTL medium scale integrated IC, ALU based computer was not going to become a practical product.

Comment: I read that Wozniak did 50 5-0 paper designs before finalizing the Apple 1. I imagine each was carefully (pencil) drawn on a 16 x 24 sheet of vellum paper.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf And [Seymour Cray](https://wiki2.org/en/Seymour_Cray) toggled in the bootstrap loader for the 1st CDC computer on the console toggles switches from memory and ...  . Those were the days.  :-)

Comment: Interesting. So it was really quite a bit of ingenuity in getting things to do they weren't really designed for.